# Авторизация: не работает переход на главную при условии ввода правильного пароля

Tags: php, html, form, авторизация

В данный момент написан самый простой php код авторизации:

```
 <?php
    $data = $_POST;
    if( isset($data['do_login']) ) {
        $user = R::findOne('accounts', 'name = ?', array($data['login']));
        if ( $user ) {
            if ( $data['password'] == $user->pkey) {
                // Если пароль правильный то должно кидать на главную
                header('Location: /');
                $_SESSION[logged_user] = $user;
            } else {
                $errors[] = '<div class="clearfix grpelem shared_content" id="u37076-4" data-content-guid="u37076-4_content"><!-- content -->
                    <p>Неправильный логин!</p>
                </div>';
            }
        } else {
            $errors[] = '<div class="clearfix grpelem shared_content" id="u37076-4" data-content-guid="u37076-4_content"><!-- content -->
                <p>Неправильный пароль!</p>
            </div>';
        }
        if( ! empty($errors) ) {
            echo array_shift($errors);
        }
    }
?>
```

По задумке кода, `header()` должен кидать на главную страницу, если пароль и логин правильный, но `header()` не срабатывает. Срабатывает он только в том случае, если я размещаю его в самом вверху страницы(!) НО, мне ведь это не подходит, мне нужно чтобы оно выполнялось когда условие на проверку логина и пароля вернет true (типо в середине кода, а не в самом вверху).

Вопрос: Как правильно использовать `header()` в данной ситуации? Может его можно указать сверху и вызвать с условия? Объясните.

Comment: `header()` можно использовать только до любого вывода в браузер. Или же, вывод надо сохранять в буфер.

Comment: можно пример внедренный в мой код?

Comment: прямо сейчас - нет, но позже зайду с ПК, напишу пример.

Comment: Вывода у тебя ни какого тут не вижу скорей всего пробел стоит в начале  файла.

Comment: @CoffeeinTime если у вас программа начинается конкретно с этого файла _(т.е., выше по коду нет ничего)_, то скорее всего причина в банальном пробеле перед открывающим тегом `   <?php`. Кстати, в вашем примере перед ним как раз и находится пробел. Я немного дописал код, чтоб можно было его запустить, и у меня редирект отработал без ошибок: [смотреть пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ef59c835e59b44b45404e1c396b882619f693a6a)

Answer (score 0):

Перед `header ( )` не должно быть  вывода в браузер. Проверь что бы до `<?php`
нет пробелов и переводов строки. Перед ним не должно быть  html тегов он должен быть в начале документа иначе `header ( )` не будет работать. Если используешь  кодировку utf-8 то она должна быть без BOM.

Comment: А в условии он будет работать? в "if" но при этом без html заголовков и тд

Comment: Напиши весь код тогда у тебя где то вывод в браузер.